# How to add an hyperplane on seaborn pairplot?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, data-visualization

I am working with seaborn pairplot to represent my data, i also have an hyperplane encoded by a slope vector and an intercept that live in the same space that my data. I would like to represent this hyperplane on the pairplot too, how to do it ?

```
slope = [1.3,0,2.31,3,0,0,0,4.1,0.9,0]
intercept = 1.7

sns.pairplot(df, hue = 'target')
```

I know how to add one line on all plot, but don't see how to add each projection of the hyperplane to it's associated plot.